Flutter and node js ERROR : ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., uri=http://ipadress:8081/login
i need help i'm working with flutter and nodejs, i think sit's cors porblem but i don't know how to fix it
i tried diffrent solutions but nothing works
even chat gpt did ot help
i need this to work in few hours , i don't have much time
this is index.js
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors'; // Import the cors package
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import http from 'http';
import { Server as SocketIOServer } from 'socket.io';
import authRoute from './routes/authRoute.js';
import userRoute from './routes/userRoute.js';
import normeRoute from './routes/normeRoute.js';
import recommandationRoute from './routes/recommandationRoute.js';
import roleRoute from './routes/roleRoute.js';
import projetRoute from './routes/projetRoute.js';
import notificationRoute from './routes/notificationRoute.js';
import { checkProjectDeadlines } from './controllers/ProjetController.js';
import cron from 'node-cron';
import db from './config/Database.js';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

// Configure CORS
app.use(cors({
  origin: '*', // Allow all origins
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'], // Adjust as needed
}));

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new SocketIOServer(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*', // Allow all origins for WebSocket
    },
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(authRoute);
app.use(userRoute);
app.use(normeRoute);
app.use(recommandationRoute);
app.use(roleRoute);
app.use(projetRoute);
app.use(notificationRoute);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});

export { io };

cron.schedule('00 23 * * *', () => {
    checkProjectDeadlines();
});

app.listen(process.env.APP_PORT, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log('Server running at port http://localhost:' + process.env.APP_PORT);
});


